# Difference between data class and class

Tags: oop, kotlin

What is the main aim of using `data class` in Kotlin?

I know it overrides `toString()`, `equals()` and `hashCode()` functions for you but I'm curios if this is the only reason for which they created this type of class.

If I create a `class` and override those three methods - using the same logic as Kotlin does - in this case my `class` would be the same as if I would declare it as a `data class`?

Thanks!

Comment: It's just a handy and short way to create classes that only hold data and don't perform any operations. The first sentence [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) is *We frequently create classes whose main purpose is to hold data.*...

Comment: So basically it is a classical DTO class which don't have any logic inside it - only attributes.

Comment: Yes, it is... It derives some utility methods from the attributes like the ones you already mentioned and a few more, like `copy()`. It's great to have such a class in a single line of code or just very few ones instead of having to write every getter, setter and so on.

Comment: I understood. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the class where you implement those methods manually is the same as put that "data" before declaration. This "data" is simply a syntax sugar. But it's more clear to use these data classes for DTO and such ones (data structures called classes)